# Heroku suddenly crashed by URI malformed, cannot be parsed

Tags: express, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have a webapp made with react express mongo running in Heorku, auto deployed by branches, my last deploy/build was working correctly, two days ave passed and I made minor changes to README.md (added mermaid gitgraph via github editor) and it suddenly crashed tis is the heroku log:

> Server now listening on PORT 28845!
> /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:580
> return callback(new MongoParseError('URI malformed, cannot be parsed'));
> ^
>
> MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed
> at parseConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:580:21)
> at QueryReqWrap.callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:127:7)
> at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/callback_resolver:49:10)
>
> Node.js v19.1.0
>
> myapp@1.0.0 start:dev
> concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"
>
> sh: 1: concurrently: not found
> Process exited with status 127

my code for the server:

```
const express = require("express");
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
// const http = require('http').Server(app);

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.use(routes);

// Connect to Mongo DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/cmx", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false, useCreateIndex: true });

// Start the API server
const server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`CMX ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {transports: ['polling', 'websocket']}); 
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  app.set("socketId", socket.id)
    console.log("New client connected",socket.id);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected", socket.id);
  });
});
```

and in ENV in heroku/config have:

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster<clustername>.mongodb.net/heroku_<clustername>?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-48xk7w-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true
```

> Consolelog to: MONGODB_URI  result in the exact same string
> My other branches deployed result in te same error when i've tried to push a new commit
> Some of my tests include making a commit with jusy one extra space an result in the same error
> I made a rollback to my prod branch and it run without problems
> The application is running without problems in local

Comment: I don't know about your MongoDB URI, but you definitely shouldn't be using `nodemon` in production.

Comment: I guess nodemon is being called because right before ending it calls dev.
First it starts in NODE_ENV = production, and then it switces to dev
```myapp@1.0.0 start:prod
node server.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that heroku updated the node version that I was using, and was not compatible with the version of mongoose used, updating dependencies solved the problem